# Spring Boot: Load security roles from yaml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application that has got method level security with `@RollsAllowed('NAME_OF_THE_ROLE')` The situation I have got is that when the application goes from dev to higher environment and from there to production the names of the security groups change. Any ideas on how I can inject name of the security in `@RollsAllowed()` based on what environment I am deploy the application to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1: Multiple tolerance** 
If the name of your role does not change in time and there is no name conflict between environments, you can use the `@Secured` annotation with the different groups depending on the environment. 
For example `@Secured({ "DEV_VIEWER", "ALPHA_VIEWER", "PRD_VIEWER"})`

**Solution 2 : Hand made**
Otherwise, if you want something, you can switch to the `@PreAuthorize` annotation with a Custom PermissionEvaluator.
Baeldung made a rather complete guide on the subject https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression

Comment: with custom evaluator isn't the problem still there? e.g. in `@PostAuthorize("hasAuthority('FOO_READ_PRIVILEGE')")` I want to make `FOO_READ_PRIVILEGE` part read from a file/something.

Comment: you can pass in parameter a generic name to the permission or even the key of the yml. and it is the `hasPermission` method which makes the resolution

Comment: As you write the `hasPermission` method yourself, you can also make sure that it doesn't take any parameter then use more relevant method names such as `hasReadPrivilege`